# Discord.py member roles check command

Tags: python, discord.py

So I tried to code a command that will outputs members that don't have a specific role but I am having some errors.

The Code

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def check(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    for member in guild.members:
        if discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Free Customers') not in member.roles:
            for guild.members in range(10):
                await ctx.send(guild.members)
```

and the error

```
  File "C:\Users\Archie Baloch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Archie Baloch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Hope I can get some help over here :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your program is in the for loop, you do `for guild.members in range(10):` where you try to set the guild.members value to 0 as part of your loop, then do `await ctx.send(guild.members)` which would be 0, then you set it to 1 and send 1, etc until you reach 9. Setting the ctx.guild.members is blocked though as it is not something you are supposed to change

I suppose that isnt what you want to do, honestly I cant figure out what you are trying to do.

To make it clear:

```
for x in range(10):
    await ctx.send(str(x))
```

would send:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

And that clearly isnt what you want your loop in your program to do